# Regular Expression for positive numbers in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that validates **only positive** numbers.
e.g.
0 is invalid.
0.123 is valid.
any positive integer is valid.
any negative number is invalid

Comment: Why is 0.123 not a positive number? Sounds like you want to find numbers of 1 or more.

Comment: @SpaceBison - Did you read the question? 0.123 is valid.

Comment: What does your input look like? Is it supposed to be the number, or is the number embedded in a string?

Comment: And what about spaces? Is `"123 "` still a valid number?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET WebForms, MVC or Data Annotations or anything else besides "C#" in your code to do validations? Each of these have their own ways to ensure your data is validated properly.

Comment: @Klass Jan .123 assumed as positive? It must be regex or an if would do?

Comment: Does it also have to match *all* positive numbers?

Comment: Apologies for the serious lack of clarity in the question and also for the late response (am on a vacation to a place without reliable internet access)!!
Anyways, I am using Asp.Net MVC and was looking to validate a decimal property in the model using Data Annotations. The property is updated with the value entered in a textbox accepting a payment amount which cannot be negative or zero. I was under the impression that regular expressions were my best bet and so googled for the same, but surprisingly was not able to find one that met all my requirements. Once back, will try the answers below.

Answer (score 7):

If you are simply trying to validate input numbers as valid positive numbers, you don't need `Regex` - simply use the `Parse` or `TryParse` methods defined on `Double` or `Decimal` and check for the value being positive.

```
decimal test;

if(decimal.TryParse(myString, out test))
{
  // parsed OK, myString is a valid decimal
  if(test > 0)
  {
    // yay, it is positive!
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, do what @Oded says. Otherwise you're going to end up with all sorts of weird stuff, such as 007 being non-positive, or 00.12 being positive.

Comment: @zmbq: `00.12` *is* positive! And you won't end up with weird edge cases if you're careful to write and test your regex properly. On the other hand, I agree 100% that Oded's answer is preferable to a regex (unless the OP has a genuine reason why they *must* use a regex).

Comment: Well, right, it is positive. Anyway, I was trying to say you don't need to be careful and cautious if you just use Oded's code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced that a regex is the best way to test for positive numbers, but if you must use a regex for some reason then this should meet your stated requirements:

```
^(?:[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?|0\.0*[1-9]\d*)$
```

Comment: +1 for the argument, a regex should not be used to parse numbers. It is a text matching tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^(?!-|0(?:\.0*)?$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?306qq)

`^` the start of the string

`(?!-|0(?:\.0*)?$)` negative lookahead assertion, fails when the string starts with "-" or a 0 and 0.0* followed by the end of the string.

`\d+` matches at least one digit

`(?:\.\d+)?` matches optionally a dot followed by at least one digit

`$` the end of the string

Comment: This will allow `0.0000` though, which presumably the OP wants to reject in the same way as plain `0`.

Answer (score -1):

this can help u

Positive Number --- `^\d*\.{0,1}\d+$`

Comment: This will give you .123 as a possitive (which is!) but it's not as in Klass Jan's example (0.123)