# Regex c# only positive numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that validates only positive numbers(integers):

0-999 and first number not 0.

My example not work:

```
string pattern = @"^\d+$";
```

How decided positive numbers pattern?

Answer (score 17):

You could force the first digit to be 1-9, and then have any or no digits follow it, like so;

```
string pattern = @"^[1-9]\d*$";
```

You can also restrict the amount of digits by putting a numbered constraint on it.

```
string pattern = @"^[1-9]\d{0,2}$";
```

The top one will accept any positive integer >0, while the bottom one will accept only 1-999.

Comment: If you feel this answer was valuable to you, you should choose it as the accepted answer, click the check mark below the score of this answer.

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
@"^[1-9]\d?\d?$"
```

1-9 followed by 2 optional digits?

Answer (score 2):

use this regular expression `^[1-9]\d{0,2}$`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to validate an input, why not using TryParse?

[Regular Expression for positive numbers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531421/regular-expression-for-positive-numbers-in-c-sharp)

```
        double result = 0;
        if (Double.TryParse(myString, out result))
        {
            // Your conditions
            if (result > 0 && result < 1000)
            {
                // Your number
            }
        }
```

Comment: or even `if (Double.TryParse(myString, out result) && result >0 && result <1000)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lot of useful regex tools online like [http://gskinner.com/RegExr/](http://regexr.com?34u1q)

there's a lot of ready to use examples from which you can start to get your own!

Answer (score -1):

The positive number with two digits after comma:

```
\d*\,\d\d
```